# Do some US airlines now charge for ANY checked baggage?

Tags: usa, airlines, luggage, fees-and-charges

I've heard that some/most US airlines charge for *any* checked luggage, even the first piece.  Is that the case?  Are there any that don't?  What kind of charges would I expect per piece if that is the case?

Comment: Your question *title* was getting close to the type we're trying to avoid ([faq]) - asking for a list of all US Airlines.  I've rephrased it slightly, but have left your question itself intact.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes indeed, most US airlines charge for all check baggage.  There are exceptions if you have "status" with either the airline themselves or with any of their affiliated airlines (eg, Star Alliance, OneWorld, etc), or if you're flying in First Class, or if you're connecting from an international flight, or if you have one of their pay-for credit cards, but for most occasional domestic travellers you'll be charged to check any bags.

The fees vary from airline to airline, but are generally fairly similar.  International trips are higher, although most airlines still do not charge for (at least) the first bag for most international trips.

The fees are available on their airlines websites.  eg, for both [United Airlines](http://www.united.com/CMS/en-US/travel/Pages/CheckedBaggage.aspx) and [American Airlines](http://www.aa.com/i18n/travelInformation/baggage/baggageAllowance.jsp) it's $25 for the first checked bag, and $35 for a second checked bag for domestic flights, and whilst the first bag is free for international flights the second will cost you up to $100.

[Virgin America](http://www.virginamerica.com/vx/fees/) depends on the type of ticket you have purchased, but is generally $25 for each of the first two check bags.

The main exception to the above is [Southwest Airlines](http://www.southwest.com/html/customer-service/baggage/checked-bags-pol.html), who do not charge anything to check your first 2 bags (with standard weight limits/etc).

Some airlines, such as [Spirit](http://www.spirit.com/optionalfees.aspx), charge different rates depending on whether you pay for your checked bags in advance ($28/$35 for domestic up to 40 pound/18kg) or at the airport ($38/$45).  Mind you, Spirit also charge you between $20 and $45 (up to $100 starting in November!) for your carry-on bag, so avoiding them completely is generally the best option.

Comment: Effectively, almost all US airlines now charge for checked luggage (even the first bag). Some airlines waive the charges for elite passengers, full fare passengers, and/or premium cabin passengers. Some airlines treat a frequent flier ticket purchased with the maximum number of miles the same as a purchased full fare ticket.

Comment: @MichaelMathews As mentioned in the answer, Southwest remains an exception to that. They still allow 2 free checked bags up to 50 lb per person. Given how heavily this factors into their marketing, I doubt it will change any time soon.

Comment: Indeed, even still in 2023, Southwest offers free checked bags.